# Transform csv-coordinates into area

Tags: qgis, cartography, area, csv

I'm working with an inventory of a species in Southern Sweden. I have recorded my findings (together with coordinates, name of the species and year of finding) and created a CSV-file with i have imported to QGIS.

Example from my data

```
Decade;species;ort;lat,long
1880;falcata;Borgholm;56.882657,16.655931
1880;falcata;Algutsrum;56.674716,16.53471
1880;falcata;Borgholm;56.882657,16.655931
```

In order to make a map that's easy to grasp I would like to collect all findings from e.g 1890 into an area, all findings from 1900 into a second area an so on. Someone that have a clue on what I can to to achieve this?

Comment: Please add some further information on how you want different species to be handled? Some sketch of the output you are looking for would be helpful too.

Comment: The result I want to achieve are that with the species' distribution organised after year of finding (an area with all findings from 1890 and so on) it will be easy to see how the distribution have changed over the years. If the area from 1900 is bigger than the area from 1890, then the spieces have increased their distribution. Sorry if I'm a bit confusing...

Answer (score 2):

and with area you mean a polygon using all "1880" points as nodes? 
In this case you should look in the Sextante toolbox for something to convert points to polygons.

Or do you think of some kind of kernel density analysis? Have a look at the plugins ["animove"](http://www.faunalia.it/animove) and the [homerangeplugin](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/HomeRange_plugin).

Comment: Yes, I mean a polygon with the outer "1880"-points as nodes and enclosing the inner 1880-points, so that all 1880-points are enclosed in one area. The "animove" seems to be an interesting plugin, but where can I find it?

Comment: Start QGIS -> Plugin Downloader -> search for Animove. You will find the plugins Triangulations and Homerange of which the latte one is probably your choice.